# Mongoose get fixed number of results for each categorical search item passed with $in

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MEAN stack based app wherein I am trying to implement search within various categories provided by the user so currently I am doing something like this -

```
Model.find({categories: {$in: [cat1, cat2]}}).exec(...)
```

My model schema has -

```
Categories: [String]
```

And I want to get equal results based on the categories provided by the user

But as expected this returns results with different number of items in each category.
Is there a better/faster way to get fixed number of results from each category on the server side in a single call instead of getting limited items for each category sequentially

Comment: Please add schema and sample data

Comment: As I mentioned above in the query I have a property categories in my model which is an array of strings and I need equal results from each of those categories